# Not able to fix the error "Recipe must specify a dataflow"

Tags: salesforcedx, einstein-analytics, tableau-crm, deployment-error, tableau

I had created a dashboard in one org and now i am trying to deploy it to a higher org environment using copado. I had created the dataset from a recipe so what i had done is that is that i had committed the waveapplication,wavedataset and waverecipe in copado. Once the changes are committed and after it is deployed i see the following error "A Recipe must specify a Dataflow".
After referring to the official [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000319274&type=1) ,
i tried to search and commit the wave dataflow which has the same name as recipe, but it was not present in the org; however i was able to retrieve the dataflow with the same name as recipe in vscode. The issue isn't resolved. Kindly help me with this.
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 6):

Who ever is facing this issue: There seems to be a bug regarding SFDX Metadata API and Tableau CRM. If you create a recipe sfdx pulls only the recipe **NOT** the required WaveDataFlow

You need to fetch the WaveDataflow manually:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m WaveDataFlow:[NAME OF YOUR RECIPE]
```

Add this file to your Package or Change Set and Deployment will work.

Comment: thanks, saved my day)

Comment: @ytiq: you're welcome... Regarding Analytics CRM (aka Tableau CRM) many things are "strange". Most horrible might be that some sort of Widget Formats are not Metadeployable. To redo all your work once you transfered a Dashboard from one Org to another Org is the pain....